# How to store input methods to text file java

Tags: java, visual-studio

I am currently trying to create a program in java that requires a client to be given a list of input methods to answer i.e. name of school, username etc....
At the beginning of the programme the client is given a 6 digit random code to identify them.

I now need to store the code as a text file to be called from memory at the end using a request ID. This is so the inputs can be edited later if need be.

How can I store input methods to text file that can be retrieved later... i cannot find appropriate code.

Comment: start here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/

Comment: There are plenty of examples that are easily searchable for.  What have you tried?

Comment: Thank you for the help i have managed to store values on the programme now using an array im just trying to save them to text files now.